# passing two dimensional C style array to Objective C method

Tags: objective-c, pass-by-reference

**.h file**

```
@interface GameState :NSObject{
int SymbolsPositions[3][5];
}
-(void)SaveCurrentGameState:(int **)Array;
@end


@interface GameViewController : UIViewController 
{
  ...
 int sequence_after_spin[3][5];
  ...
}
-(Void)AMethod;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
@implementation GameState
-(void)SaveCurrentGameState:(int **)Array
{   
    for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
     for(int j = 0;j<3;j++)
       NSLog(@" %d",Array[j][i]);
}
 @end


@implimentation GameViewController
-(void)AMethod
 {
   [instanceOfGameState SaveCurrentGameState:sequence_after_spin];
  }
@end
```

the application crashes when ever AMethod is called iget following warning

```
warning: incompatible pointer types sending 'int [10][5]' to parameter of type 'int **' [-pedantic]
```

Comment: Add the crash log too. Crash might be for a different reason.

Comment: `int**` and `(*int)[5]` are not the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument needs to take an array of int[][5], the reason for this is because the compiler needs to know the number of columns to correctly identify where the members are. You could also specify int[10][5] as the parameter type if you always take the same size array.

Answer (score 0):

While there could be other errors, one I see is

```
for(int i;i<5;i++)
    for(int j;j<3;j++)
        NSLog(@" %d",Array[j][i]);
```

You are not setting an initial value to `i` and `j`. `i` and `j` could be any garbage value.

```
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
    for(int j = 0;j<3;j++)
        NSLog(@" %d",Array[j][i]);
```